# How to check if same option is selected in a dynamically created form rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Been trying for hours but cannot get it right how can i check if an option is already selected in another select. Where am creating my form rows dynamically with the same class for all the newly created select.

below is how my form is after being created dynamically.

```
<select class="tank_id" name="Form[tank_id][]">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select class="tank_id" name="Form[tank_id][]">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select class="tank_id" name="Form[tank_id][]">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

what i want to achieve is to make sure the data submitted does not have duplicates. My issue is to find out if an option is already selected in a previous select below is the js i have tried but haven't achieved anything with it.

```
        $(".tank_id").on('change', function(){

            var inputs = $('.tank_id');

            var result = inputs.filter(function(i,el){
                return inputs.not(this).filter(function() {
                    return this.value === el.value;
                });
            });

            if (result.length > 0) {
                alert('match found')
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
$(".tank_id").on('change', function() {
  var current = $(this);
  var inputs = $('.tank_id').not(this);

  var result = inputs.filter(function(i, el) {
    return $(current).prop("selectedIndex") === $(el).prop("selectedIndex");
  });

  if (result.length > 0) {
    alert('Error: Selected Already')
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="tank_id" name="Form[tank_id][]">
  <option hidden>Select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select class="tank_id" name="Form[tank_id][]">
  <option hidden>Select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select class="tank_id" name="Form[tank_id][]">
  <option hidden>Select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly all i had to do to make this work with my dynamic form rows was to use $(staticAncestors).on(eventName, dynamicChild, function() {}); for it to listen to events on the newly created rows.

Comment: Just note that this doesn't compare the `value` of the items, but the order in the dropdown. So if the order might change, and/or the values might not be the same, this will have to be adapted.

Answer (score 1):

This will only check if the value you're currently selecting is already selected in another list. So if you have selected `2` in the first two dropdowns, and then selects `1` in the last, the last won't give an error message.

```js
$(".tank_id").on('change', function() {
  var currentValue = $(this).val();
  var inputs = $('.tank_id').not(this);

  var matches = inputs.filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() === currentValue;
  });

  if (matches.length > 0) {
    alert('The current selectbox value is already selected somewhere else!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="tank_id" name="Form[tank_id][]">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select class="tank_id" name="Form[tank_id][]">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select class="tank_id" name="Form[tank_id][]">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```